# rails sqlite adapter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm following the instructions in [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:demo_users_resource) and got stuck when trying to use the scaffold command.

When running:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I get the error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.4), already activated sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
```

Running:

```
gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, activerecord-nulldb-adapter, activerecord-spatialite-adapter, activerecord-simpledb-adapter
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'  
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'  
...
```

I'm running on Windows 7 x64 OS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I noticed that my Rails installation has both SQLite 1.3.3 and 1.3.4 I changed my Gemfile from:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
```

to:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'
```

That solved the problem. Thanks [@holger-just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just) for pointing me to the relevant line in the error message in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371897/211563).

Comment: I added mine exactly like this: gem 'sqlite3'. And that solved that same problem for me :-)

Answer (score 10):

suggested install command:

```
gem install activerecord-jdbc-sqlite3-adapter
```

actual install command:

```
gem install activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter
```

Reference:
http://kenai.com/jira/browse/ACTIVERECORD_JDBC-19

Answer (score 3):

The important part of your error message is this snippet:

```
can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.4), already activated sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

To fix that, you should always run your commands through `bundle exec` like so

```
bundle exec rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

That way, you give bundler to take full control over your `$LOAD_PATH` which will probably resolve these issues.

Comment: Thanks @Holager exec didn't solve the problem but you pointed me to the relevant line in the error message. This helped me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

i had this error too, buy my problem was slightly different. 
the issue is that sqlite3-ruby is deprecated, to be replaced by sqlite3. in michael hartl's webcast, he still used the old sqlite3-ruby.

I edited my gemfile to use sqlite 1.3.4 instead of sqlite3-ruby 1.3.1.
re-ran bundle install, and voila, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
```

run

```
gem install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

Also on Rails Tutorial, ran:

```
  $ rake db:migrate
```

Got the following error:

> Please install the sqlite3 adapter: gem install
>   activerecord-sqlite3-adapter (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add
>   it to Gemfile.).

Ran:

`$ gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`

Got:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>=
>   0) in any repository

Changed Gemfile according to one of the answers above:

> gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'

Got another error so had to install:

```
$ gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'
```

Tried running $ rake db:migrate again, but got another error, this time resembling the answer above:

> Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.5),
>   already activated sqlite3-1.3.4. Make sure all dependencies are added
>   to Gemfile.)

So changed Gemfile to:

> gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'

And got another error message to make sure 'gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5' succeeds (wtf?! alright again). Installed it successfully, ran bundle install.

Tried running:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Nothing happened, so tried:

```
$ bundle exec rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

Per another suggestion above. And it finally worked. The tutorial warned of a laborious setup process, but I felt like I had to mix and match from at least 5 other people. Hope this helps the next person.