# Cannot start a new rails server - sqlite.3h is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am trying to run a rails server on ruby on my Windows 7 operating system. I made a new rails application but when I try to run the server I get the following error:

```
D:\projects\RubyOnRails>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
D:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please
install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the  bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Trying to install `activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`:

```
D:\projects\RubyOnRails>gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, activerecord-bq-adapter, activerecord-simpledb-adapter, activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

After I try to install the `sqlite3` gem I get the following error (I also had to install the DevKit to be able to proceed up to this step):

```
D:\projects\RubyOnRails>gem install sqlite3
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

D:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

In the `System32` folder I have the `sqlite3.dll`, `sqlite3.exe` and `sqlite` export definition file.

Also, the sqlite3 seems to be working fine:

```
D:\projects\RubyOnRails>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.16.2 2013-04-12 11:52:43
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Also, my bundle is up to date:

```
D:\projects\RubyOnRails>bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

However in my gemfile there is no information about the version of the sqlite3 gem and when I put one the server fails to start:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
```

Please help!

Comment: try 'gem update --system' and then start server

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371809/rails-sqlite-adapter-error). Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using ruby 2.x (currently beta and not working with sqlite3) instead of 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install sqlite3-ruby gem instead of sqlite3 only

Go to http://www.sqlite.org, and download sqlitedll under "Precompiled Binaries For Windows". Extract the file and put two files sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.def in the ruby bin's directory, i.e., C:\ruby\bin.
Run "gem install sqlite3-ruby" to install sqlite3-ruby gem. (Try "gem install --version 1.2.3 sqlite3-ruby" if the latest version is not working)

Comment: Hello when I run `gem install --version 1.2.3 sqlite3-ruby` I get the same error - D:\projects\RubyOnRails>gem install --version 1.2.3 sqlite3-ruby
Fetching: sqlite3-ruby-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    D:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for fdatasync() in -lrt... no
checking for sqlite3.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: This might help you. Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371809/rails-sqlite-adapter-error