# Error starting server with rails server, sqllite error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have just installed Ruby193 and Ruby200, and I'm trying to load the server after creating a new application but I'm getting the error below.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integ
ration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `ge
m install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add
it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resol
ve_hash_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resol
ve_string_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'

    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `esta
blish_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/a
pplication.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/r
ailtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Workspace/RailsTest/app_name/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (r
equired)>'
    from C:/Workspace/RailsTest/app_name/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from C:/Workspace/RailsTest/app_name/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from C:/Workspace/RailsTest/app_name/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Workspace/RailsTest/app_name/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:40:in `eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.
rb:200:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.
rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.
rb:254:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've replaced the sqlite3 gem with gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0' and ran bundle install but it hasn't done anything. I've also tried installing the alternatives they suggest in error but it throws an error as well

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any
repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sq
lserver-adapter, activerecord-bq-adapter, activerecord-simpledb-adapter, activer
ecord-mysql2-adapter
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Bundle Show gives
    Gems included by the bundle:

- actionmailer (3.2.13)
- actionpack (3.2.13)
- activemodel (3.2.13)
- activerecord (3.2.13)
- activeresource (3.2.13)
- activesupport (3.2.13)
- arel (3.0.2)
- builder (3.0.4)
- bundler (1.3.5)
- coffee-rails (3.2.2)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- hike (1.2.2)
- i18n (0.6.1)
- journey (1.0.4)
- jquery-rails (2.2.1)
- json (1.7.7)
- mail (2.5.3)
- mime-types (1.23)
- multi_json (1.7.3)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rack (1.4.5)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.3)
- rack-test (0.6.2)
- rails (3.2.13)
- railties (3.2.13)
- rake (10.0.4)
- rdoc (3.12.2)
- sass (3.2.9)
- sass-rails (3.2.6)
- sprockets (2.2.2)
- thor (0.18.1)
- tilt (1.4.1)
- treetop (1.4.12)
- tzinfo (0.3.37)
- uglifier (2.1.0)

Database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Can you show us your gemfile?

Comment: i've added the gem file there

Comment: how does your database.yml look like? Can you post your "bundle show"

Comment: added database.yml and bundle show

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371809/rails-sqlite-adapter-error for a similar question. Have you installed sqlite3 (on windows), and which gem is installed? sqlite3 is not listed in the `bundle show` command. I think you will need the [Ruby DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) when installing sqlite3 on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.

I reinstalled rails, ruby, devkit using the [rails installer](http://ruby.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=ruby&cdn=compute&tm=7&f=10&su=p284.13.342.ip_p504.6.342.ip_&tt=29&bt=8&bts=31&zu=http://railsinstaller.org/). Works perfectly now.